# OpenVPN "use this connection only for resources on its network" not allowing access to VPN hosted site (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: openvpn, ubuntu-20.04, networkmanager

I am connected to a VPN using OpenVPN. Everything was working fine but the network administrator informed me I had unusually high traffic. I inspected my VPN settings and realised I had forgotten to check "Use this connection only for resources on its network" for IPv4 and IPv6.

I set this, and I can still access the network folders, but now I cannot access a site that is hosted on the VPN. What can I do to fix this?

From my googling, it seems that checking that setting adds a default gateway to the VPN. So I assume for public websites it first checks my default gateway, finds it and resolves the IP. For this VPN hosted site I would assume it would try the default, not find anything, move on to the VPN gateway, find it and resolve the IP. Networking is not my strong point however, any clarification of the process would be appreciated.

I'm using gnome network manager on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Any luck solving this? I have the same problem. If no "Use this connection only for..." is checked, then I can only access my VPN hosted sites and no internet. If the value is checked - internet is working, but some of the VPN hosted sites can't be reached.

Comment: Sorry, no. I just had to deal with it.

Comment: I found a way by setting a DNS to 8.8.8.8 (Google DNS) on my Wifi network. Using this DNS everything works fine both on network side and local VPN sites.